# YAML::Tiny does not support JSON::XS::Boolean

Tags: json, perl, yaml

When reading some JSON data structures, and then trying to `Dump` them using `YAML::Tiny`, I sometimes get the error

```
YAML::Tiny does not support JSON::XS::Boolean
```

I understand why this is the case (in particular `YAML::Tiny` does not support booleans, which `JSON` is keen to clearly distinguish from other scalars), but is there a quick hack to turn those `JSON::XS::Boolean` objects into plain `0`'s and `1`'s just for quick dump-to-the-screen purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[YAML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML%3a%3aTiny) doesn't support objects.  Unfortunately, it doesn't even have an option to just stringify all objects, which would handle `JSON::XS::Boolean`.

You can do that fairly easily with a recursive function, though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010; # for say

use JSON::XS qw(decode_json);
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed reftype);
use YAML::Tiny qw(Dump);

my $hash = decode_json('{ "foo": { "bar": true }, "baz": false }');

# Stringify all objects in $hash:
sub stringify_objects {
  for my $val (@_) {
    next unless my $ref = reftype $val;
    if (blessed $val) { $val = "$val" }
    elsif ($ref eq 'ARRAY') { stringify_objects(@$val) }
    elsif ($ref eq 'HASH')  { stringify_objects(values %$val) }
  }
}

stringify_objects($hash);

say Dump $hash;
```

This function doesn't bother processing scalar references, because JSON won't produce them.  It also doesn't check whether an object actually has overloaded stringification.

[Data::Rmap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aRmap) doesn't work well for this because it will only visit a particular object once, no matter how many times it appears.  Since the `JSON::XS::Boolean` objects are singletons, that means it will only find the first `true` and the first `false`.  It's possible to work around that, but it requires delving into the source code to determine how keys are generated in its `seen` hash:

```
use Data::Rmap qw(rmap_ref);
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed refaddr);

# Stringify all objects in $hash:
rmap_ref { if (blessed $_) { delete $_[0]->seen->{refaddr $_};
                             $_ = "$_" } } $hash;
```

I think the recursive function is clearer, and it's not vulnerable to changes in `Data::Rmap`.

Comment: I added a question related to this as an answer so I could post code.

Comment: Hmm.. actually it doesn't work if one of the values (e.g. `true`) appears more than once. For some reason only the first boolean gets stringified. Any idea why?

Comment: @JuanAntonio, it's because there's only one `true` object and one `false` object.  JSON::XS just references it multiple times.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @cjm, thanks! this is pretty much what I ended up doing in the end. Thanks for your solution!